# mod_rewrite to alias one file suffix type to another

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I hope I can explain this clearly enough, but if not let me know and I'll try to clarify.

I'm currently developing a site using ColdFusion and have a mod_rewrite rule in place to make it look like the site is using PHP. Any requests for index.php get processed by index.cfm (the rule maps *.php to *.cfm).

This works great - so far, so good. The problem is that I want to return a 404 status code if index.cfm (or any ColdFusion page) is requested directly.

If I try to block access to *.cfm files using mod_rewrite it also returns a 404 for requests to *.php.

I figure I might have to change my Apache config rather than use .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `S` flag to skip the `404` rule, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Do not separate these two rules so long as the first has S=1
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1.cfm [S=1]
RewriteRule \.cfm$ - [R=404]
```

If you are also using the `Alias` option then you should also add the `PT` flag. See the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Post the rules you already have as a starting point so people don't have to recreate it to help you.

I would suggest testing [L] on the rule that maps .php to .cfm files as the first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two distinct groups of rewrite rules, one for .php, the other for .chm and make them mutually exclusives with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}. And make use of the flag [L] as suggested by jj33.

You can keep your rules in .htaccess.